# How to change ThreeJs background on scroll

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a CubeTextureLoader to set the sky of my scene: my website is divided in three sections and I don't know how to change scene.background smoother between every section while I'm scrolling.

My thought is to have many images and change the index while I'm scrolling.

Is there an easy way? Are there some other solutions instead CubeTextureLoader?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: how about https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_crossfade

Comment: I'll try...I'm not sure because I need to change only the background scene without the object...

Comment: You render 2 scenes, each with their own background. Then use the post processing to fade between one and the other